# How to load images in opencv using python?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: Print `img.shape`, one of its dimensions is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It does mean that there is no image to show.
check the image type and the path again.